# Обращение к элементу массива

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 20
            [0] => 20
            [NAME] => Пример
            [1] => Пример
            [ID_USER] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [D_FORM] => 1535979327
            [3] => 1535979327
            [PA] => 1
            [4] => 1
        )

)
```

Есть массив но при обращении к нему $item['NAME'], выдает ошибку не могу понять почему

Comment: Какую соственно ошибку?

Comment: Undefined index: NAME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас массив в массиве. Обращайтесь вот так: `$item[0]['NAME']`

Comment: Спасибо помогло, а может есть вариант записи более лаконичный, просто элемент в массиве будет всегда 1 $item[0]

Comment: `$first = array_shift($item);` - сохраняет первый элемент массива в отдельную переменную

Answer (score 0):

У вас массив в массиве. 
`$array` ваш массив

```
   foreach($array[0] as $item){
    echo $item['NAME'];
    }
```

Comment: В моем случае не имеет смысла, в указанном массиве всегда 1 запись [0]

Comment: ну я предлогаю хорошый вариант  для всех  случаех

Comment: Вопрос только в том, что зачем перебирать массив если заведомо известно, что элемент только 1

Comment: ну для утого  Yuriy Prokopets писал хорошую function array_shift()